# Magento product view not working when connected as client

Tags: magento

I am running Magento CE 1.6.0.

I have a unique store. I can see products lists and product view when visitor. I can see products lists when connected as client but I can't see product view. I get a "There has been an error processing your request" page instead.

Somebody has an idea?

Here is the error log :

```
a:5:{i:0;s:77:"SQLSTATE[21000]: Cardinality violation: 1242 Subquery returns more than 1 row";i:1;s:6638:"#0 lib/Varien/Db/Statement/Pdo/Mysql.php(110): Zend_Db_Statement_Pdo->_execute(Array)
#1 lib/Zend/Db/Statement.php(300): Varien_Db_Statement_Pdo_Mysql->_execute(Array)
#2 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(479): Zend_Db_Statement->execute(Array)
#3 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Abstract.php(238): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#4 lib/Varien/Db/Adapter/Pdo/Mysql.php(389): Zend_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Abstract->query('SELECT COUNT(DI...', Array)
#5 lib/Zend/Db/Adapter/Abstract.php(825): Varien_Db_Adapter_Pdo_Mysql->query(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#6 lib/Varien/Data/Collection/Db.php(217): Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract->fetchOne(Object(Varien_Db_Select), Array)
#7 lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(225): Varien_Data_Collection_Db->getSize()
#8 lib/Varien/Data/Collection.php(211): Varien_Data_Collection->getLastPageNumber()
#9 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(996): Varien_Data_Collection->getCurPage()
#10 app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(831): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->_loadEntities(false, false)
#11 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Upsell.php(74): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->load()
#12 app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List/Upsell.php(94): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell->_prepareData()
#13 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(862): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_List_Upsell->_beforeToHtml()
#14 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#15 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('upsell_products', true)
#16 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(155): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('upsell_products')
#17 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#18 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#19 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#20 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#21 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#22 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#23 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#24 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#25 app/design/frontend/base/default/template/page/2columns-right.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#26 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#27 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/base/d...')
#28 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#29 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#30 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(529): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#31 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(391): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#32 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(132): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#33 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#34 app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route')
#35 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(420): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#36 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#37 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#38 app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(347): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#39 app/Mage.php(640): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#40 index.php(80): Mage::run('', 'store')
#41 {main}";s:3:"url";s:25:"/basics-blenders-textures";s:11:"script_name";s:10:"/index.php";s:4:"skin";s:7:"default";}
```

Comment: You have an error in your store somewhere. You can see what the error is by viewing the error file that is generated /var/report , post the error here if you want more information on what is wrong.

Comment: I don't understand why customer_logged_in vs customer_logged_out can change the way you view a product.

Comment: I have created a new product with default attributes because I thought my imported custom products could be the source of the problem but I still can't view a product when customer logged in...

Comment: You possibly have added the Same Block twice in XML Layout handle customer_logged_in

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP and MySQL versions were not meeting [Magento system requirements](http://www.magentocommerce.com/system-requirements)